# How to find the matches in the given List

Tags: java, regex, string, list, string-matching

I want to write a method that takes as an input a `String` `key` separated by white spaces and a list of `String` in which matches have to be searched.

The format of the string `key` could be like this:

> "s1 **or** s2 s3 **or** s4"

It has to be translated to a condition "(**s1** `or` **s2**) `and` (**s3** `or` **s4**)", where conditions grouped with `or` are always executed first.

The method should return a list of strings which match the condition obtained from the specified the "key".

```
public List<String> search(String key, ArrayList<String> s){
    ...
}
```

**Example** of the input (a `key` and a list):

```
// if ((s.contains("i") || s.contains("you")) && (s.contains("boy") || s.contains("girl")) then store in the List and return finally
String key = "i or you boy or girl"; 

ArrayList<String> s = new ArrayList<String>(
            Arrays.asList("hello world",
                          "i am a boy",
                          "i am a girl"));
```

Then the resulting list would contain string:

```
`"i am a boy"` and `"i am a girl"`.
```

Comment: You split the `String` into parts by space.  In your example, the only logical operator is or.  Then you find the `Strings` that match each of the remaining tokens.  Finally, you merge the duplicate `Strings`.

Comment: So the problem is how to parse the "string predicate" and find out is there at least one element in the list that matches this predicate?

Comment: how about if the key string is like "i you or boy girl"?

Comment: @jennaa How this key should be interpreted "A or B or C D"? `(s.contains("A") || s.contains("B") || s.contains("C")) && s.contains("D")` ?

Comment: you can ignore the consecutive `or` @AlexanderIvanchenko

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done with [**predicates**](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Predicate.html) (*function represented by a boolean condition*) and **regular expressions**.

The overall idea is to generator a `Predicate` based on string `key` and then to test list elements against this predicate.

The process of parsing a `Predicate` is done in following steps:

- Split the key into groups, that has to be combined afterwards with logical `AND`, based on following regular expression **`"(?<!or)\\s+(?!or)"`**

  - `(?<!or)` - **negative lookbehind**, represents group of characters before the matching string that must not be equal to `"or"`;
  - `(?!or)` - **negative lookahead**, represents group of characters after the matching string that must not be equal to `"or"`;
  - `\\s+` - matches a string comprised from one or more *white spaces*.
- Split each group of strings obtained at the previous step on the `" or "` and combine the obtained predicates with logical `OR`.
- Combine predicates generated at previous step into a single predicate.

(*for information on regular expressions take a look at [this tutorial](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)*)

Then we need to iterate over the given list and apply method `test()` of the combined predicate to every element. Elements that meet with the predicate will be added into the resulting list.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String key = "i or you boy or girl";

    List<String> source =
            List.of("hello world", "i am a boy", "i am a girl");

    Predicate<String> predicate = getPredicate(key);
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();

    for (String next: source) {
        if (predicate.test(next)) {
            result.add(next);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(result);
}

public static Predicate<String> getPredicate(String key) {
    Predicate<String> result = str -> true;

    for (String next: key.split("(?<!or)\\s+(?!or)")) {
        Predicate<String> pred = str -> false;

        for (String target: next.strip().split(" or ")) {
            if (target.isEmpty()) {
                continue;
            }
            pred = pred.or(str -> str.contains(target));
        }
        result = result.and(pred);
    }
    return result;
}
```

**Output**

```
[i am a boy, i am a girl]
```

**Note:**

- A base for combining predicates with **or** (`||`) has to yield `false` because only in this case it'll not affect the result (*with (`||`) only **one** condition can be `true` and the overall result will be evaluated to `true`*).
- A base for combining predicates with **and** (`&&`) has to return `true` because only so the result will not get affected (*with* `&&` ***all** the conditions needs to be evaluated to `true` for the overall result to be `true`*).